# ¿Porque altera el objeto a otro objeto ? c++

Tags: c++

¿Porque altera al objeto original esta declaración?

```
Nodo *nodo_nuevo;
Nodo *i;
i = nodo_nuevo;
delete i;

cout<<nodo_nuevo->dato<<endl;
/*error*/
```

Y cuando quiero ver los datos del "nodo_nuevo" ya no están ¿por qué?

Comment: No soy un experto en C++ , pero no es porque i apunta a nodo_nuevo y luego borras i?

Comment: @Capt.Teach edite mi pregunta, perdón si me equivoque.

Comment: Estamos claros en que son dos apuntadores que _apuntan_ a alguna dirección de memoria. Cuando asignas, asignas la dirección de memoria a la que debe apuntar el nuevo. Luego haces delete. ¿Qué hace delete?

Comment: No es que los datos ya no estén, es que nunca estuvieron.

Comment: Asumiendo que `nodo_nuevo` alguna vez apunto a una dirección de memoria que asignaste con `new`, al darle la misma direccion de memoria a `i` y hacer `delete i;`, se han borrado los datos a los que apuntan `i` y `nodo_nuevo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Porque altera al objeto original esta declaración

Tienes un error de concepto. No estás usando objetos sino punteros

Lo primero que voy a hacer es corregir tu código:

```
Nodo * nodo_nuevo = new Nodo; // Asumo que existe constructor por defecto
Nodo *i;
i = nodo_nuevo;
delete i;
```

Vale, vamos a ver qué es lo que sucede.

Lo primero que se hace es crear un objeto de tipo Nodo en el montón (*heap*). La función `new` nos devuelve la posición de memoria donde se aloja dicho objeto. Por ejemplo 0x100:

```
nodo_nuevo = 0x100
```

Después declaras otro puntero `i` que no está inicializado, es decir, apunta a una posición de memoria basura o aleatoria

```
nodo_nuevo = 0x100
i          = 0xC34
```

Siguiente paso, se igualan ambos punteros. Lo que hace este paso no es duplicar el objeto almacenado en `0x100` sino copiar **su dirección de memoria**. Es decir:

```
nodo_nuevo = 0x100
i          = 0x100
```

Es decir, ambos punteros apunan a la misma región de memoria y, en consecuencia, ambos punteros leen y modifican el mismo objeto.

A continuación se libera la memoria direccionada por `i`, es decir, se destruye el objeto almacenado en 0x100. Este cambio, como ves, afecta a ambos punteros, pues ambos se quedan apuntando a memoria no válida.

La última operación es irrelevante ya que esa memoria, suponiendo que puedas leerla, no tiene por qué tener datos válidos. Esa memoria ha podido ser utilizada por otro proceso y tener información de cualquier tipo.

Para copiar objetos tienes que desreferenciar los punteros:

```
Nodo* nodo_nuevo = new Nodo(1);
Nodo* i = new Nodo(2);
*i = *nodo_nuevo;
delete nodo_nuevo;

cout << i->dato << '\n'; // Imprime 1
delete i;
```

En este ejemplo no estamos usando un objeto sino dos (por eso tenemos dos `new`). Es decir, `nodo_nuevo` apunta a una región de memoria, por ejemplo en 0x100, mientras que `i` apunta a otro objeto situado en una posición de memoria distinta, por ejemplo 0x120.

Como son dos objetos diferentes, la vida de uno de los objetos no está condicionada por la vida del otro. Así, destruir el objeto al que apunta `nodo_nuevo` no tiene impacto alguno en el objeto apuntado por `i`.

Comment: Ah ya osea al final tiene el mismo comportamiento que los punteros tradicionales . Muchas gracias.